# Adding Jbuttons and Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So my code already makes a starting menu made of buttons and a label. When one of the buttons is pressed I want to remove everything (Which it does) and show a new label and a button. Only the new items do not appear, please help

```
public void HighScoreScreen(String HighScores){
    //first we need to get rid of what's already there (this works)
    remove(title);
    remove(newGameButton);
    remove(twoPlayerButton);
    remove(highScore);

    //now adding what I want to show (doesn't work)
    highScoreSheet = new JLabel(HighScores);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(highScoreSheet, gbc);

    menu = new JButton("Menu");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    add(menu, gbc);
    repaint();
}
```

I think that's all that's relevant but if you need the code where I first make the menu here it is:

```
   public GUI(){
    super("Snake Game");

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 0); 

    title = new JLabel("SNAKE");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(title, gbc);

    newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(newGameButton, gbc);

    twoPlayerButton = new JButton("2 player Mode");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;       
    add(twoPlayerButton, gbc);

    highScore = new JButton("HighScores");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;        
    add(highScore, gbc);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

    newGameButton.addActionListener(handler);
    twoPlayerButton.addActionListener(handler);
    highScore.addActionListener(handler);

}
```

The action lister this code refers to is in a class within this class and works fine, when highscore is pressed it will do its thing then call the first code block I showed.

And finally here is the main, just in case you need it:

```
public class SnakeGame extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public boolean read = false; 

public SnakeGame(){

    GUI frame = new GUI();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void run(){

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SnakeGame Game = new SnakeGame(); 

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix AWT components in a Swing Application. Canvas is AWT. Use a JPanel for custom painting.

The basic code when adding/removing components on a visible GUI is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint();
```

If you don't invoke the layout manager then the components have a 0 size so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: .... or swap with a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). 1+

Comment: ... and I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels , in this case because you are replacing ALL the components you should just swap panels by using the `CardLayout`. So I would take the few extra minutes to restructure your code to use the CardLayout instead of just using the suggest I provided.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about mixing AWT and swing but I've added the revalidate line and now it works great thanks so much :)

Comment: swapping panels does seam more efficient

Comment: @CameronWhittle, Look in the API. A Canvas is part of the `java.awt.*` package. A JPanel, JButton etc belong to `javax.swing.*` package. You should not use an AWT component in a Swing application because painting of components is done differently in AWT and Swing which can lead to problems. `swapping panels does seam more efficient` - it is also better for structuring and maintaining your code because you have separate panels that each do one function as oppose to one panel that does two functions.